# In what case would a programmer get the webApplicationContext out of DispatchServlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I notice that there is `getWebApplicationContext` in `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController`. This means that spring programmers can use `getWebApplicationContext` to access beans in the spring IoC container.

However, I never see people use this way to get beans in all the spring MVC tutorials. So here comes my question, in that case would a programmer want to get the `WebApplicationContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an odd question... are you asking why a method is in the API if none of the tutorials use it? Do you expect every API method to be in the tutorials?

The `getWebApplicationContext()` method is rarely used by application code, but it is used internally by Spring for some tasks.

Comment: The reason I come up with this question is that I am working on a project that involves the behavior of Spring MVC programmers. I have to support ideally any spring MVC usage.

Comment: One of Spring MVC's strengths is that there are a hundred different ways to do any given thing. You can't cover them all.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases when you implement `org.springframework.web.servlet.View` a call to getWebApplicationContext can be useful to get access to Spring beans that can not (or should not) be passed along in the `Model` object.

Answer (score 1):

You also might need it when implementing custom JSP tags to access Spring Beans e.g. But this is usually a method you try to avoid from application code.

Comment: The ViewResolver can expose Spring beans to the JSP, no need to fetch the beanfactory yourself.